# Precise meaning of "have had experience"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm trying to figure out what exactly the sentence below means.

> In the past several years, I **have had experience** in video editing and cooking.

I want to communicate that I had lots of practice in video editing and cooking, but that sentence reads somewhat strangely for me. Does that sentence mean that I *used to have experience (so perhaps I no longer have experience)?* Or does it mean that I've gotten lots and lots of practice in video editing and cooking, so maybe I'd be proficient in it?

Is that an acceptable sentence to express what I want to express? Or would I be better off writing an unambiguous sentence like "In the past several years, I partook in many video editing and cooking activities."

Comment: Well, "no longer have experience" is an impossibility - you cannot change the past. However, "have had" has no implication that there was a large or small amount of experience, so if you want to say that you have "lots and lots" of experience, then you need to say that more explicitly. I would also say that your final sentence remains ambiguous - "several" and "many" are subjective terms, so if you can actually quantify your experience ("in the past six years I've produced and edited an average of ten videos per month"), that's far less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to English Language Learners.

If you say, "I have had experience", the amount of experience you've had is not communicated. Most people would assume that if you don't communicate the amount it's either not important or it's not enough to be impressive.

In your case you have a goal of communicating that you've had a lot of experience so it's best to be clear and unambiguous

> In the past several years I've had a lot of experience in video editing and cooking.
> In the past several years I've had enough experience in video editing and cooking that I'm very good at them.
> In the past several years I've had 6 months of full-time experience in video editing and a year of experience in cooking dinner every day for my family.

Nobody would assume that you no longer have experience because experience is a thing that can't be undone. However, if your experience was a long time ago they might suspect that you no longer remembered what you had learned from your experience.